# Scanner object executes only one time in while loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a situation where the program will take input for total no of string to be inputted.
Once inputted it will print odd and even indexes of the string in one line separated by a space. 
For illustration this should be the output for the follwing input:
2
input
ipt nu
output
otu upt

my logic seems fine but when I am trying to execute the program runs for only one time whatever be the input. Can anyone please let me know what am I missing here.

Code snippet

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javatest 
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String input_string;
        int inputs = scan.nextInt();//total inputs to be accepted
        int i=0;
        while(i<inputs) 
        {
            input_string = scan.nextLine();
            //for even places
            for (int j = 0; j < input_string.length(); j += 2) 
            {
                if (j % 2 == 0) 
                {

                        System.out.print(input_string.charAt(j));
                }
            }
            System.out.print(" ");
            //for odd places
            for (int k = 1; k < input_string.length(); k += 2) 
            {
                if (k % 2 == 1) 
                {
                    System.out.print(input_string.charAt(k));
                }
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

The above code is producing the output as 
3 
hello 
hlo el 
(execution ended)

Comment: execution ended, or is it waiting for you to provide more input?

Comment: Your code looks OK, but as @Stultuske pointed out, you will need to provide a new string each time after the program prints out your modified input.

Comment: @Stultuske  the issue is if I input 3 my code only accept one string and the execution ends abruptly whereas the desired behavior should be if 3 is the input it should accept 3 Strings as Input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: @avvinm I just copy pasted your code and ran it here. you are mistaken. it waits for more input (though only twice). you need to add a scan.next(); after your scan.nextLine(); (and some printouts "ENTER DATA") to make it more clear to you that the execution isn't terminated

Comment: You should **follow the Java Naming Conventions**: class names are always written in PascalCase (first letter is uppercase), variable and method names are always in camelCase (first letter lowercase).

Comment: @MCEmperor though that would make the code more readable, it wouldn't really change the behaviour

Comment: @Stultuske It indeed does not. But it will save a lot of hurt in the future, so it's best to mention it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By pressing `enter` upon entering the amount of inputs you are creating a *newline* `\n` character which is consumed by the `input_string = scan.nextLine();` in your `while` loop. So directly after entering the amount of inputs the `while` loop will increment the value of `i` to `1` as it processes the `\n` character.

As a workaround you could fetch the amount of expected inputs as a `String` and parse it to an `int` like this:

```
int inputs = 0;
try {
    inputs = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // handle exception gracefully, maybe by showing a message to the user.
}
```

Also to make it more clear for the user to understand that an input is expected you might want to add a message that makes it clear a new input is expected:

```
System.out.println("Please provide the next input: ");
input_string = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: Got you. I am new to Java. Will make a note of this naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `scan.nextInt()` does not read the enter pressed while inputing the number. Due to this issue your program runs 1 iteration lesser than the input.
I ran your exact code without any modification and it runs twice for input 3.

The first call to `scan.nextLine()` gives an empty string.

The alternative can be replacing

`scan.nextInt()` with `Integer.valueOf(scan.nextLine());`

which will read the enter/new line character also.